# How can I use the Accelerometer for detecting jump in LibGDX?

Tags: android, libgdx, accelerometer

I make an app for android. I'll use the accelerometer for detecting jump.Does someone know how that works?
And which value will change and with how much?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some of the methods:

```
// Check accelerometer availability on device
boolean available = Gdx.input.isPeripheralAvailable(Peripheral.Accelerometer);

// Get current orientation
// Orientation.Landscape or Orientation.Portrait
Orientation nativeOrientation = Gdx.input.getNativeOrientation(); 

// Reading values
float accelX = Gdx.input.getAccelerometerX();
float accelY = Gdx.input.getAccelerometerY();
float accelZ = Gdx.input.getAccelerometerZ();
```

You will have to write your own function to combine above values and get a threshold or range of values to detect jump.

Reference: [libgdx accelerometer](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Accelerometer)

Comment: Thanks! But if the mobile is in landscape moding which value changed? And how much change the value?

Comment: Don't know. You can display x,y,z values in a sample app, and see what is happening to each when you move/shake/jump.